# Selecting time series data based on values of preceeding records

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset of streamflow, precipitation, and time as POSIXct. I'm trying to subset those records where there has been no precipitation during the preceding two hours and it is night (for my purposes, say between 10PM and 4AM).

The dataset is "complete" in that there are hourly records, even when the flow and precip are na, so I could convert to a time series. I'm pretty sure I could kludge this together with a loop, but would like to do better.

Example dataset is:

```
sample <- structure(list(flow = c(1.4838542618848, 1.68681348430786, 1.49091679298032, 
0.904015076235029, 1.67419864019143, 1.39869975622123, 0.797317388543118, 
1.34068054355126, 2.68070195855211, 2.27260130448352),
rain = c(0.1,0.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
datetime = structure(c(1104523200, 1104526800, 1104530400, 1104534000, 
1104537600, 1104541200, 1104544800, 1104548400, 1104552000, 1104555600), 
tzone = "GMT", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("flow","rain",  
"datetime"),row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pre2prec <- filter(is.na(sample$rain),c(0,1,1),sides=1)==2
night <- as.POSIXlt(sample$datetime)$hour > 22 & as.POSIXlt(sample$datetime)$hour < 4

sample[pre2prec & night,]
```

Unfortunately you did not set the time zone for your time values. `as.POSIXct` then uses the time zone of the current system. Since I am in Europe and apparently you are not, your dataset doesn't contain any night values for me.

Comment: You know, this is why I come here. Things that I think are going to be a mess can actually be done in three lines of code. FWIW I edited the sample data to demonstrate things better, but you pretty much nailed it. Thanks!